# Do the $2$ modulus $3$ can be $-1$ or just $2$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I need to calculate $2$ modulus $3$ as $2<3$ then the answer should be $2$ but instead in a math problem they use it as $-1$. Is this possible? thanks

Comment: What "math problem"? Providing the context should generate more directed answers for you.

Comment: Yes 2 and -1 are the same modulo 3

Comment: @Sloan is a mathematical induction problem but is not relevant.

Comment: It is relevant: $2 \mod 3 = 2$ but  $-1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical expression $a \equiv b \pmod c$, which is read "$a$ is equivalent to $b$ *modulo* $c$", means that $c$ divides the difference $b - a$ (or $a - b$, since it cannot divide one without dividing the other). So because $(2) - (-1) = 3$ is a multiple of $3$, we get $2 \equiv -1 \pmod 3$. Indeed $$\ldots \equiv -7\equiv -4 \equiv -1 \equiv 2 \equiv 5 \equiv 8\equiv \ldots \pmod 3$$
So it is not a single number equivalent to $2 \bmod 3$, but an entire class of numbers.

Sometimes - particularly when dealing with computers - it is useful to have a single representative of that class instead of the whole thing. Such a representative value is called a "residue", and a "complete set of residues" is a value for all possible classes modulo $c$. Now the most obvious choice for a complete set of residues is the values $\{0, 1, \ldots, c-1\}$. But this is only one possible choice, and depending on the problem at hand, it may not be the most convenient choice. So there is no universally established convention here.

In computer science, you don't have the luxury of redefining the meaning according to the problem at hand. So most computer languages will define $a \bmod b$ to be the residue between $0$ and $b$. But in mathematics such notations can vary with the context. So somewhere around this proof, or in the book or course it came from, they should have specified a meaning (unless you mixed up the notation "$-1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$" with the notation "$2\bmod 3$").

Comment: I changed to \bmod and \pmod as appropriate.

Comment: Right you are. The computer scientists have a binary operation “$a\bmod n$”, which delivers the smallest nonnegative number $x$ for which there’s an integer $r$ with $a-x=rn$. It’s useful to the computer scientists, not so useful in mathematics.

Comment: @BillDubuque - Thanks. I was unaware of those variations.

Comment: @Paul Some authors do use \mod for \pmod, i.e. they omit the parentheses, but that makes even more possibility for confusing the   *ternary relation* \pmod vs. *binary operation* \bmod, so for questions like this it is best to avoid the possible ambiguities due to such overloading. But, of course, it's your answer so you are free to use the notation you like.